# RASA preprocessing, user entered text

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am new to RASA. I gone through updated documentation Rasa 3 but I don't know how to pre-process the message of the user before nlu-model.

e.g., if user enter `hi`, so i want to read that text before any action taken by rasa like tokenization etc.

If anyone can please guide me for this.

EDIT: I want to capture user text in rasa itself, before any other pipeline action, so that I can do my own processing. (for learning purpose)

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario, you can handle the user message from front end (chatbot widget), specifically from JS script.